# If/Else with C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

Okay, so I'm working with some if/else statements now. But, I'm having some trouble.

Here's the full code that is depending on the version clicked.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        file.Filter = "File(*.file)|*.jar|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        file.Title = "Open File...";
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fullFileName = item.FileName;
            FileInfo userSelected = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
            string fileNameWithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
            string destPath = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt);
            string mcAD = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%");
            File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD, true);
        }
    }
```

But what I'm having trouble is with this. 
Below is the code, but here's how the program is lain out.
There's a menu at the bottom of the program. It's named "Version" you click and you can choose version 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0. I have it set so there's text beside it telling it which version you chose. 
Now, the issue is I need an if/else statement for all the version for the above code cause all files for each version go to a different location.

Here's the other code...

```
private void Version_1_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Version_1_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "1.0 Selected";
}

private void Version_1_6_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Version_2_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "2.0 Selected";
}

private void Version_3_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Version_3_0_Selected = VersionText.Text = "3.0 Selected";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean each version goes to a different location? Do you mean the folder that is initially opened?

Comment: Well dang forgot to put in. I had a File.Copy function in there and each version copies the file to a different location in the AppData folder which is the main reason I need the if/else statement

Comment: the "other" code seems pointless, it declares a string, assigns something to it, then that string goes out of scope ( gets deleted )

Comment: @KeithNicholas I put it in there so you had all my code. Nothing is really special about it but the part where the user clicks. I need it so when the user clicks on it, it runs a certain function in the if/else statement in button_click

Comment: @zespri it's just a string, nothing special about it.

Comment: @MatthewH string does not have `FileName` property. So it is not "just a string". What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Control.Tag for storing version index. For example:

```
private void Version_1_0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  VersionText.Text = "1.0 Selected";
  VersionText.Tag= 1;
}
```

Then, you can define your target paths:

```
string[] paths = {@"c:\path1.txt", @"c:\path2.txt", @"c:\path3.txt"};
```

Finally, when you writing your files you can lookup the path like this:

```
File.Copy(item.FileName, paths[VersionText.Tag], true);
```

You might need to modify this code if the target file name is based on the source file name, but that should not be difficult.

Comment: Hm, let me try this instead.

Comment: @MatthewH The compiler is telling you that it is expecting and int, but it instead is getting an object. You need to tell it that the object you have is an int by casting it. You could use something like int.TryParse to safely cast it

Comment: @madbrendon Never heard of that. What would an example code be?

Comment: @MatthewH when compiling and getting a error message you don't understand, try googling it. On your level of language knowledge, you most likely get it resolved on the first few hits. For this one see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304696

Answer (score 1):

Abstract the FileDialog code to a separate method and pass in your version string so that you can then perform the checks.

```
public void OpenVersionDialog(string version)
{
     string mcAD = GetCopyPath(version);
     if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mcAD))
     {
        using (OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            file.Filter = "File(*.file)|*.jar|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            file.Title = "Open File...";
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               string fullFileName = item.FileName;
               FileInfo userSelected = new FileInfo(fullFileName);
               string fileNameWithExt = Path.GetFileName(fullFileName);
               string destPath = Path.Combine(Application.UserAppDataPath, fileNameWithExt);


               File.Copy(item.FileName, mcAD, true);
            }
        }
     }
     else
     {
        //invalid version selected
     } 
}


public string GetCopyPath(string versionInput)
{
   //these are case-insensitive checks but you can change that if you want case-sensitive
   if(string.Equals(versionInput, "1.0 Selected", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return "YOUR_PATH_FOR 1.0";

  if(string.Equals(versionInput, "2.0 Selected", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return "YOUR_PATH_FOR 2.0";

   if(string.Equals(versionInput, "3.0 Selected", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      return "YOUR_PATH_FOR 3.0";

   return String.Empty;
}
```

If I understand correctly that should be what you want. If you have more versions, you could store them in a dictionary where the key is the version and the value is the path that the file should be copied to.

I'm not sure what the difference between `mcAD` and `destPath` is but I assume `mcAD` is the variable that changes based on the version as that's being used in `File.Copy`.

Comment: Let me try. I'll let you know if it works. It may take me a few minutes though. It should work though. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: @MatthewH - I don't know what that `buttonModdedJAR_Click` is (it's not in your question) or how you're calling but it seems that the signature for that handler is incorrect.

Comment: it was just the function name. button_click is the same exact thing

Comment: keep the button_click event like you have in your question but within that, call the `OpenVersionDialog`. Don't try and link your button's click handler to the `OpenVersionDialog` method directly.